# How to make IntelliJ reformat code inside style tag for React

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I want IntelliJ to reformat code inside of a `<style>` tag in a React JavaScript(jsx) file. When I reformat code now it just reformats JavaScript parts.

I simply want the code to change from this:

[image]

to this automatically:

[image]

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me using CSS injection with comment (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18307#u=1490109456558):

```
// language=CSS
    return (
    <div>

        <style>{`
            * {
                color: red
            }
        `}</style>
    </div>
);
```

[image]

Comment: your code makes anything inside return() being interpreted as CSS although there is jsx code inside return most of the time